# Javascript to extract branch and leaf informations

Tags: javascript

I am a bit novice in JS and drafting a JS code to parse and create a HighChart options structure. The XML file has content in following format

**Series->DrillDown->Data->Series->DrillDown->Data...**

The last 'Data' branch will have 'point' node. Below is the XML (filename: ex.xml) file I receive as an AJAX call made via Jquery:

```
<chart>
     <categories>
        <name>'MSIE'</name>
        <name>'Firefox'</name>
        <name>'Chrome'</name>
        <name>'Safari'</name>
        <name>'Opera'</name>
      </categories>
      <name>'Browser Brands'</name>
      <data>
             <series>
               <y>55.11</y>
               <drilldown>
                  <name>'MSIE versions'</name>
                  <categories>
                      <name>'MSIE 8.0'</name>
                      <name>'MSIE 6.0'</name>
                      <name>'MSIE 7.0'</name>
                      <name>'MSIE 9.0'</name>
                  </categories>
                 <data>
                     <series>
                       <y>33.06</y>
                       <drilldown>
                           <name>'drilldown next level'</name>
                            <categories>
                              <name>'a'</name>
                              <name>'b'</name>
                              <name>'c'</name>
                            </categories>
                            <data>
                              <point>23</point>
                              <point>54</point>
                              <point>47</point>
                             </data>
                       </drilldown>
                     </series>
                   <point>10.85</point>
                   <point>7.35</point>
                   <point>2.41</point>
                 </data>
               </drilldown>
             </series>
             <series>
               <y>21.63</y>
                <drilldown>
                <name>'Firefox versions'</name>
                <categories>
                    <name>'Firefox 3.6'</name>
                    <name>'Firefox 4.0'</name>
                    <name>'Firefox 3.5'</name>
                    <name>'Firefox 3.0'</name>
                    <name>'Firefox 2.0'</name>
                </categories>
                 <data>
                    <point>13.52</point>
                    <point>5.43</point>
                    <point>1.58</point>
                    <point>0.83</point>
                    <point>0.20</point>
                 </data>
               </drilldown>
             </series>
             <series>
               <y>11.94</y>
               <drilldown>
                <name>'Chrome versions'</name>
                <categories>
                   <name>'Chrome 10.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 11.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 8.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 9.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 12.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 6.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 5.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 7.0'</name>
                </categories>
                <data>
                   <point>9.91</point>
                   <point>0.50</point>
                   <point>0.36</point>
                   <point>0.32</point>
                   <point>0.22</point>
                   <point>0.19</point>
                   <point>0.12</point>
                   <point>0.12</point>
               </data>
               </drilldown>
               </series>
               <series>
               <y>7.15</y>
               <drilldown>
               <name>'Safari versions'</name>
               <categories>
                   <name>'Safari 5.0'</name>
                   <name>'Safari 4.0'</name>
                   <name>'Safari Win 5.0'</name>
                   <name>'Safari 4.1'</name>
                   <name>'Safari/Maxthon'</name>
                   <name>'Safari 3.1'</name>
                   <name>'Safari 41'</name>
               </categories>
               <data>
                   <point>4.55</point>
                   <point>1.42</point>
                   <point>0.23</point>
                   <point>0.21</point>
                   <point>0.20</point>
                   <point>0.19</point>
                   <point>0.14</point>
               </data>
            </drilldown>
           </series>
           <series>
              <y>2.14</y>
               <drilldown>
               <name>'Opera versions'</name>
               <categories>
                  <name>'Opera 11.x'</name>
                  <name>'Opera 10.x'</name>
                  <name>'Opera 9.x'</name>
               </categories>
                <data>
                   <point>1.65</point>
                   <point>0.37</point>
                   <point>0.12</point>
                 </data>
                </drilldown>
            </series>
        </data>
</chart>
```

Now I am writing the JS code to parse and set the HighChart options. The objective is to set chart options to something like below :

```
struct Series{
    float y:
    struct DrillDown{
        char name[SIZE];
        char categories[SIZE][SIZE];
        struct Data{
            struct Series * series;
            float points[SIZE];
        };
    };
}; 

struct Series seriesOptions;
```

As in XML tree structure format. This Series structure would then be set as HighChart options:

```
options.series.push(seriesOptions);
```

where options is already defined array in the JS script.

So I traverse thru XML tree for each Series->for each DrillDown->for each Data->if series is there then traverse repetative Series->for each DrillDown->for each Data->set Data points:

```
$.get('ex.xml', function(xml) {
                    var $xml = $(xml);
                    $xml.find('chart categories name').each(function(i, category) {
                            options.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
                    });
                    chart.setTitle.push($xml.find('chart name').text());
                    $xml.find("chart data series").each(function(i, series){
                                            var seriesDownSearch = function(){
                                                    var series = $(this);
                                                    var seriesOptions = {
                                                            y: parseInt(series.find('y').text()),
                                                            drilldown : []
                                                            }
                                                    series.find("drilldown").each(function(i, drilldown){
                                                            //set drilldown name leaf,categories branch name leaf and data branch
                                                            $(drilldown).find("data").each(function(i, data) {
                                                                    //set data point and loop if series branch is present
                                                                    $(data).find("series").each(seriesDownSearch);
                                                            });
                                                    })
                                            }();
                   });
});
```

My issue is that how I set and create the commented code as **//**. Note that **'name leaf, categories branch name leaf and data branch'** has to be an element of 'drilldown' and **'option'** of **'data' element defined in 'drilldown'**. Such that they can be accessed under one structure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: .. so, you simply want to parse XML with javascript ?

Comment: Yes, but also I have to generate HighChart Data options?